# How to show this is a topological basis

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

According to Robert Conover,A First Course on Topology : *Definition 6.3* pg 73

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space A collection $\mathfrak{B}$ of subsets $X$ is
a **basis** for the topology $\tau$ if

1. Every member of $\mathfrak{B}$ is open in $(X, \tau)$ and
2. Each open subset of $(X ,\tau)$ is the union of a
   collection of sets in $\mathfrak{B}$ in $X$

What I have to prove is on  **pg 74, Theorem 6.5**

**Theorem**
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then the
collection $\mathfrak{B}=\{B_{1/n}(x):n\in Z^+\text{ and }x \in X\}$ is a basis for the metric topology on $(X,d)$

**My attempt**

It is obviously a local basis but showing it as a basic open set is giving me problems

1. If $B(x, \frac{1}{n}) \subset B(x;n)$
   for each $n>2$, $\mathfrak{B}$ is open
2. To see $\bigcup$ $\mathfrak{B}$.
   Fix $n=2$ $x\in B(x;\frac {1}{2})=\{x\}$

Then $\bigcup \{x\}=X$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's not the usual definition of basis. That's usually the definition of an open covering.

Comment: @Arthur is right. In general, this definition is even wrong. Take for instance $\mathfrak{B} = \{X\}$. This satisfies your two conditions. However, if $\#X\geq2$ and if $X$ is discrete, $\mathfrak{B}$ certainly isn't a basis.

Comment: Here is the actual wording @Authur

Comment: Your right this def is of open covering. Funny Conover could not give the correct definition

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated where the question came from. This is often better context than just "your attempt", as for example here folk could check to see if this is the "actual wording" or not. For example, there may be some assumption earlier which means that this usage of "basis" makes sense.

Comment: A First Course in topology Conover @user1729

Comment: @Plotinus Please edit this into the question, along with precisely *where* in the book you found this (so folk don't have to dig through the entire book to understand you).

Comment: Ok I have added it into the question @user1729

Comment: @Plotinus edit in the book title too, and use sentences. Say "I am reading A First Course in topology by Conover. Page Y has the following definition:... Then Thereom 6.5 on p74 says..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false in general that $B(x,1/2)=\{x\}$, but it is true that $x\in B(x,1/2)$. Your definition of basis also needs a third condition which says that for any $A\in \tau$ and $x\in A$ there is a $B\in \mathfrak{B}$ such that $x\in B\subset A$. To see that any $B(x,r)$ is open you only need to check that for any $y\in B(x,r)$ there exists a $r'>0$ such that $B(y,r')\subset B(x,r)$, since this is the definition of an open set with the metric topology (in particular any $B(x,1/n)$ is open).

Comment: That comes under the definition of local basis

Comment: I was talking about the general definition you wrote down. It should specify then that $\mathfrak{B}$ is a local basis for any $x\in X$. However, is more usual and less confusing simply adding the third condition.

Comment: The above Def is called basic open sets,so I find it kind of strange Conover didn’t mention last condition.

Comment: Given a basis $\mathfrak{B}$, a basic open set is a member of $\mathfrak{B}$.

Comment: B(x,1/2)={x} wild be true if d induced the discrete topology

Comment: Yes, taking $d(x,y)=0$ if $x\neq y$ and $d(x,x)=1$ would define $d$, and this is called the discret metric. But, as I said, in general this is not true, so you cannot use this fact in a demonstration where $d$ is any metric.

Comment: No third condition is needed. Your proposed third condition is simply a rewording of condition 2 in the post.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, now. But not before edited.

Comment: @LeeMosher The old second condition only required that $\bigcup \mathfrak{B} = X$, wich is not sufficient and I was referring to that.

Comment: Ah, I should have compared time stamps. Sorry about that.

Comment: @LeeMosher Don't worry, it's ok.